# iOS iPhone ZBar get scanned image

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, barcode, scanning

How can I get ZBar to not only return me a barcode text string but a UIImage of scanned barcode as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include something like this in the class that implements ZBarReaderDelegate:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD:  get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol* symbol = nil;

    for (symbol in results)
    {
        // grab first barcode
        break;
    }

    // do something with barcode data
    qrCode.text = symbol.data;

    // do something with barcode image
    // BELOW IS HOW YOU GET THE SCANNED IN IMAGE
    //
    resultImage.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // dismiss controller
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Comment: this delegate method is not getting called in my code any help ?

Comment: [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] returns the complete image captured by camera.. But how to get the barcode iamge alone?